# Docker container resolve.conf gets overwritten all the time

Tags: docker

I had to change dns settings and did it in `/etc/resolve.conf` file in container with `docker exec -it /bin/bash`. But this gets overwritten after a while. Not sure why. The host (hyperv Linux) has correct dns settings. Host itself is a hyper-v vm in a windows server 2012.

Comment: If you need to override your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, you should be mounting it. You didn't provide much information but it is possible that the container has been recreated. Any changes that are made while execing into the container will not persist.

Comment: Do you mean the volume? It has a volume but it’s not mapped to /etc/resolve.conf path. It’s mapped to /var/jenkins

Comment: You would need another volume for that file so it is persistent like your Jenkins folder.

Comment: Been reading that stuff under /etc are maintained by docker. Especially the dns.